# The command '/bin/sh -c ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: linux, docker, ssh, nestjs

Could anyone can help me to fix this error?

I've tried several solutions on stackoverflow but none of them can fix the error I encountered.

can anyone help me to fix this error.

I was stuck fixing this problem, and please tell me which part is wrong in my script.

Due to this problem, my work was stuck, causing the implementation schedule to be delayed for an indefinite amount of time.

Gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build_push

variables:
  DOCKER_REPO: repo
  DOCKER_USER: user
  DOCKER_PASSWORD: password
  CI_COMMIT_TAG: latest
  SERVICE_NAME: service

build_push:
  stage: build_push
  script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
    - echo "building docker image"
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_TAG .
    - echo "pushing image to docker hub"
    - if [ $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH = "develop" ]; then docker push $DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA; fi
    - if [ -n "$CI_COMMIT_TAG" ]; then docker push $DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_TAG ; fi
    - echo "docker image $SERVICE_NAME has been successfully pushed to docker hub"
  only:
    - develop
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
RUN apk update
RUN apk add openssh
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN npm config set strict-ssl false
RUN npm config set proxy ${http_proxy}
RUN npm config set https-proxy ${http_proxy}
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:lts-alpine as production-stage
RUN apk update
RUN apk add openssh
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN npm config set proxy ${http_proxy}
RUN npm config set https-proxy ${http_proxy}
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
CMD [ "node", "dist/main" ]
```

Log Gitlab

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
  on auth-runner 3tZsAfwR
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on prodi...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/3tZsAfwR/0/universitas-terbuka/praktik-ut-auth/.git/
Checking out b51d2149 as panca-test-docker...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ echo "building docker image"
building docker image
$ docker build -t $DOCKER_REPO:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA .
Step 1/30 : FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
 ---> 7f1893c3ede0
Step 2/30 : RUN apk update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f3c135d9ba44
Step 3/30 : RUN apk add openssh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2095837bd75
Step 4/30 : RUN mkdir /root/.ssh && chmod 0700 /root/.ssh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 074d7c835ebb
Step 5/30 : RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1dea639e8240
Step 6/30 : RUN ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
 ---> Running in 6d98e25ba480
The command '/bin/sh -c ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74 >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts' returned a non-zero code: 1
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: What was the fix?

Answer (score 1):

The `ssh-keyscan -t rsa 172.168.85.74` is used to scan the public key of `172.168.85.74`. In a normal case, it should return something like:

```
172.168.85.74 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC9doCmMIs...
```

From your log, you did not return anything, this means the build container which you used to build the image could not get key or cannot access the `172.168.85.74`. Then the command `exit with 1` which make the build failure. You should make sure the build machine could ping `172.168.85.74`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ssh-keyscan` is included in package `openssh-client-common`

```
apk add openssh openssh-client-common
```